# Combining datasets and formatting them Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, func

How would I be able to create a function where it combines `data1, data2 and data3`. the code has to combine all the columns that are in common with all 3 datasets so `Low` in `data1` is not common with `data2/3` so it will be excepted. The data is sorted in synchronous order and each row has to be unique, no two dates can be the same. In `data2` `data3` the row that contains the date: `2021-10-21 00:03:00` but only a single row of that data is in the output because it is not a a unique row. How would I be able to do this code?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import functools

data1 =pd.read_csv('dataset1.csv', low_memory=False)
data2 =pd.read_csv('dataset2.csv', low_memory=False)
data3 ==pd.read_csv('dataset3.csv', low_memory=False)
```

data1 csv:

```
Unix Timestamp  date                    Symbol    Open      High      Low 
1444311600000   2015-10-08 13:40:00     BTCUSD    10384.54  10389.08  10340.2
1444311660000   2015-10-08 13:41:00     BTCUSD    10389.08  10389.08  10332.8
1444311720000   2015-10-08 13:42:00     BTCUSD    10387.15  10388.36  10385
```

data2 csv:

```
Unix Timestamp  Date                    Symbol    Open       High 
1634774460000   2021-10-21 00:01:00     BTCUSD    4939.95    4939.97    
1634774520000   2021-10-21 00:02:00     BTCUSD    4959.18    4961.75
1634774580000   2021-10-21 00:03:00     BTCUSD    4964.33    4964.33
```

data3 csv:

```
Unix Timestamp  Date                    Symbol    Open       High
1634774580000   2021-10-21 00:03:00     BTCUSD    4964.33    4964.33
1634774640000   2021-10-21 00:04:00     BTCUSD    4800.2     4867.47
```

Expected Output:

```
Unix Timestamp  date                    Symbol    Open      High      
1444311600000   2015-10-08 13:40:00     BTCUSD    10384.54  10389.08  
1444311660000   2015-10-08 13:41:00     BTCUSD    10389.08  10389.08  
1444311720000   2015-10-08 13:42:00     BTCUSD    10387.15  10388.36
1634774460000   2021-10-21 00:01:00     BTCUSD    4939.95    4939.97    
1634774520000   2021-10-21 00:02:00     BTCUSD    4959.18    4961.75
1634774580000   2021-10-21 00:03:00     BTCUSD    4964.33    4964.33
1634774640000   2021-10-21 00:04:00     BTCUSD    4800.2     4867.47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use append and then drop_duplicates

```
data1.drop('Low',1).append([data2, data3], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: can you also be selective about which columns to be imported, lets say if I only wanted to import `Symbol` and `Open`.

Comment: You would need to drop them  from each dataframe I think

Comment: the `drop_duplicates()` does not work.